# Auto deducing a type template argument from a dependent non-type template argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I defined a class template `X` like this:

```
template <typename T>
using Func = void(T);

template <typename T, Func<T> F>
class X { ... };
```

Now I can use class `X` like this:

```
void func(int i);

X<int, &func> x;
```

It seems redundant to me to repeat the type `int` in the declaration of `x`. Is there a way this can be auto deduced? I mean I want to have a type template `Y` which can be used via `Y<&func>` and equals `X<int, &func>` with auto deduced `int`.

I tried a lot, even defining crazy templated functions and using `decltype`, but it seems there is no way to drop the `T` before naming of `&func`.

**Update**: It seems to be a restriction that I am using MSVC 2017.5 which prevents me from using `auto` in template parameter lists as suggested by Kerrek. I wonder if there is some "hack" to get the same effect without this feature.

Comment: A typical "hack" people used before C++17 involves a helper function declaration, `decltype` and a macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, use `auto` and specialize partially:

```
template <auto F> struct X;

template <typename T, void (*F)(T)> struct X<F>
{
    // ...
};
```

Usage:

```
void f(int);

X<f> x;   // deduces T = int, F = f in the partial specialization
```

Comment: [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mj7RhnivKbwjQwt2), [demo using references](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9GZNZ5GMWj6yjUQZ)

Comment: This is awesome. But it seems my compiler (MSVC 2017.5) does not support auto in template parameter lists. It gives C3533.

Comment: @M.Winter: You didn't specify that limitation in your question.

Comment: @NicolBolas I am still lucky that this possibility was brought to my attention. I was not aware of auto in template parameter lists. I will edit my question.

Comment: @M.Winter: You're the one who tagged the question with "c++1z". If you didn't mean that, change your tags?

Comment: @KerrekSB Oh I write c++17, thats what my compiler advertises. I just did not know that this feature was missing. For most parts c++17 syntax should be okay.

Comment: @M.Winter: Complain to your vendor for false advertising :-)